# Recursively create a php file in all subfolder in a given folder

Tags: php

I want to create an empty index.php file in all subfolder of a given folder path i specify.

That is, say given folder is `/dir/content`, with many sub folders, I want `index.php` to be added to all the sub folders. If one exist already, skip.

A php function to achieve this is what I want.

Comment: using php or bash  ?

Comment: using PHP not bash

Comment: I would have likely used a bunch of conditional logic, but php does have a `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` that I have never used. http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php seems like a good start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) and [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/recursivedirectoryiterator.construct.php).

The following code will create an empty `index.php` file in each directory, if one does not exist.

```
<?php
$root = './';

$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $file = realpath($file);
    if (is_dir($file) === true) {
        if (!file_exists($file.'/index.php')) {
            echo 'CREATED: '.$file.'/index.php</br>'.PHP_EOL;
            file_put_contents('', $file.'/index.php');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use php copy function. here is the documentation,

[php copy function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

here is an example,

```
function recurse_copy($src,$dst) {  
    $dir = opendir($src); 
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) { 
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
                recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
            else { 
                copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($dir); 
    //echo "$src"; 
} 
$src = "/home/user/public_html/dir/subdir/source_folder/";  
$dst = "/home/user/public_html/dir/subdir/destination_folder/";  
recurse_copy($src,$dst);
```

Comment: I want a to recursively add a file to every sub directory in a folder. Copy wouldn't do that.

Comment: give your folder locations using copy functions recursively.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the [scandir](http://php.net/scandir) function:

```
putFiles('/startDir');

function putFiles($path)
{
    fopen("$path/index.php", "w");

    $files = scandir($path);
    unset($files[0]); // remove .
    unset($files[1]); // remove ..

    foreach($files as $filePath)
    {
        if(is_dir("$path/$filePath"))
        {
            putFiles("$path/$filePath");
        }
    }
}
```